# Three.js - THREE.MeshLambertMaterial: 'texture' is not a property of this material

Tags: javascript, three.js

The project currently involves a spinning cube. I desire to add dice textures to the sides using MultiMaterial that includes MeshLambertMaterials.

At this point, I have my spinning cube.
[Spinning Cube Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f45q2.png)

I loaded in the textures (it loads in as they show up in chrome inspector) using this piece of code. My pictures are called 1.jpg, 2.jpg...

```
const loadTextures = () => {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    let materials = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        const texture = textureLoader.load('./assets/textures/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg');
        materials[i] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ texture });
    }

    return materials;
}
```

Then I use said array of MeshLamerMaterials to initialize a MultiMaterial. Then I add it to the Cube Mesh that works (pic 1) using this code.

```
const createCubeMesh = (width, height, depth) => {
    const materials = loadTextures();

    const   geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth),
            material = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials),
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    return mesh;
}
```

Yet, when I run the code I get these warnings, not errors: [Error & pic load in proof image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v23BH.png). And the textures don't load. [Texture doesn't load Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f45q2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the issue myself but still wanted to share it for people who had the same issue. I forgot to add the 'map' as property for the texture I put in each MeshLambertMaterial.

```
materials[i] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map:texture });
```